# How can I avoid gaps between cards when I open them?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi I want to make simple web page.[As you see in the link there are 4 cards which I can open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqw9M.jpg).
When I open card B,[a gap occurs between the card A and card C.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdeUp.jpg) I could not understand why it happens.

[As you see in here, I uploaded my html codes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPQ4f.jpg)
Can you tell me the solution of my problem ?

Comment: create runnable snippet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use columns to achieve what you are trying to do. Of course you'll need to check how it will behave when you go responsive:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        ...A div here
        ...C div here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        ...B div here
        ...D div here
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the bottom element `position: absolute;` and the father `position: relative;` (with a clearfix class). In this way the element is not considered by the DOM.